# SQL Select Case Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, case, data-conversion

With the help of case statement, I would like to get the result as "Non Revenue" in Geodept column where the value is 0

Simple case statement - (gives conversion error)

```sql
case when GeoDeptId = 0 then 'Non Revenue' else GeoDeptId end
```

So tried as below but getting value as 0 again

```sql
convert(int, case when IsNumeric(convert(int, rd.GeoDeptId ))= 0 then convert (varchar(14),'Non Revenue') else rd.GeoDeptId
end ),
```

So tried as below but getting value as 0 again

```
convert(int, case when IsNumeric(convert(int, rd.GeoDeptId ))= 0 then convert (varchar(14),'Non Revenue') else rd.GeoDeptId
end )
```

Comment: What is the data type of `GeoDeptId`?

Comment: Possibly subjective, especially given the number of times I see it done otherwise, but I am not a big fan of forcing UI data into SQL. My approach to this would be to return either `NULL` or `0` to the UI, and deal with any user friendly presentation there. In doing the conversion in SQL early, your taking away information from the UI regarding the underlying type. FWIW I do things like this all the time in ad hoc code, but in production code I would avoid it, so not saying there's no good reason to know how to do it, just do it with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `GeoDeptId` to text:

```
CASE WHEN GeoDeptId = 0 THEN 'Non Revenue' ELSE CAST(GeoDeptId AS varchar(max)) END
```

The source of your error is that all branches of a `CASE` expression must have the same type.  Since it is not possible for `'Non Revenue'` to be cast to an integer, therefore we can convert the `GeoDeptId` to text.

Comment: Why a `MAX` length value?

Comment: Because I don't know the _exact_ type of integer and hence I do not know the exact width I might need.

Comment: But no numerical datatype can be longer than 8,000 characters. If my memory serves, the longest would be 40 characters for a `decimal` (38 digits, a minus and decimal point).